# Outputting formula based on list of strings

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two lists:

```
n <- 'winner'
p_list <- c('qualified', 'female', 'apple')
df_features <- c('female','qualified','admission','apple_B','apple_C','apple_D')
```

I want to generate a formula like so given p_list and df_features:

```
winner ~ apple_B + apple_C + apple_D + female + qualified
```

Basically I am given `p_list` and `n`. I want to create a formula with `n` being the outcome and `p_list` being the regressors. However if one of the elements in `p_list` is not in `df_features`, I want to alter that element to be replaced by anything with the same text before the underscore (_) from `df_features`. So apple would be replaced by apple_B + apple_C + apple_D. Hopefully this makes sense.

How can I do this in R (I prefer a solution if dplyr if possible).

I've tried this so far:

```
f <- as.formula(paste(n,"~",paste(p_list,collapse="+")))
```

But right now the solution is not accounting for `df_features` and the altering of the variable apple.

I'm also able to check if values in `p_list` are in `df_features` by `p_list %in% df_features`, but not sure how to use it right now.

Comment: Your code is broken, `'`-vs-`"`. Please test your code before you put it in a question.

Comment: Updated. sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` out from the `df_features` those matching `p_list` and use with `reformulate` to produce the formula.  No packages are used.

```
reformulate(unlist(sapply(p_list, grep, df_features, value = TRUE)), n)
## winner ~ qualified + female + apple_B + apple_C + apple_D
```

Comment: nice use of `reformulate`

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by G. Grothendieck is so good, I almost feel shame of posting mine. However, I'll do, as I find that sometimes going the long way gives you additional knowledge of the tool at hand:

```
as.formula(paste0(n, 
                  " ~ ", 
                  paste(c(p_list[p_list %in% df_features == TRUE],
                        grep(p_list[p_list %in% df_features == FALSE],
                             df_features, 
                             value=TRUE)), 
                        collapse = "+")))
```

What is in there:

- `as.formula` converts strings to formula.
- `paste0` will paste the string stored in `n`, the tilde and the result of `paste`.
- `paste` will concatenate, *using "+" as collapser* (`collapse = "+"`):
- those elements of `p_list` that are in `df_features` (hence `TRUE`)
- and it will grep on `df_features` those that are not a direct match (`FALSE`), returning the values and not the indexes (`value = TRUE`).